# is const (c++) optional?

Tags: c++, constants

according to some tutorials i read a while back, the **"const"** declaration makes a variable "constant" ie it cannot change later.
 But i find this const declaration abit inconveniencing since the compiler sometimes gives errors like
`"cannot convert const int to int"`
or something like that.

and i find myself cheating by removing it anyway.

**question:**
assuming that **i am careful about not changing a variable in my source code**, can i happily forget about this const stuff?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put another way:  "I make mistakes in const-correctness.  If I never make mistakes in const-correctness, can I stop using const?"

Comment: You should use `C`, it's much easier to shoot oneself in the foot (and you would not risk a leg)

Comment: Something it's useful to use `mutable` fields of a class, when you need only "logical" persistence, but not "physical" one. Of course this approach is more error-prone, but sometimes there is no way better.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Are you serious? Why would you want to give up on such a useful feature just because you make a mistake sometimes? Better try and learn to avoid mistakes with `const` and you benefit from the great assistance it adds to ensure correctnes with your code.

Of course, you can say goodbye to all the help the language provides, and tell the compiler thereby not tell you about mistakes in your code anymore. Instead, you will have to ask the debugger later on where your bugs are. Not sure whether that's better.

Comment: +1 "You can let the compiler tell you now, or ask the debugger to tell you later." Very nice.

Comment: +1 Good answer. It's not only a great help at compile time, it's also a nice form of documentation. You can see which variables can change and which cannot, which can save you a lot of time when reading code.

Comment: +1 The only time I don't use const as much as possible is when existing S/W isn't const correct and I'm refactoring it to be const correct bit-by-bit. I'd much rather know right at compilation that I'm changing something I didn't intend.

Comment: @helpermethod but const doesn't actually stop the variable from being changed because people could still cast it out right... this has been bothering me for days now :)

Answer (score 14):

In C++, "const" can a apply to a variable (making it unchangeable) or a function (rendering it unable to change other things).

My use of "const" is not just to prevent my code from changing my variable. It's to prevent some idiot's code from changing my variable (especially if the idiot is me six months from now) and to prevent my code from changing a critical variable some idiot left exposed (especially if the idiot was me six months ago).

Comment: const cannot be applied to a function, only a member function.
If it's in a function, you are really applying it to the arguments of the function.


class A {
public:
  void f() const; // f cannot change members of A, ie const A* this;
};
void g(const A& a); // the argument a is const

Comment: @Dov, true, const cannot apply to *all* functions, only to *member* functions. And even a const (member) function can change *some* other things. I was trying for brevity, not rigor.

Comment: I have been looking into the how and why of const but I can't seem to shake the fact that even though it's suppose to prevent code from changing the variable, it really doesn't, because someone can still cast the const away... so I am still looking...

Comment: @ioSamurai: It prevents someone from changing it *casually, by accident*. Yes, some people know about `const_cast` and don't understand how dangerous it is, and there has been debate about whether that should be in the language or not. Do you have a specific problem in mind?

Comment: @Beta thanks, and no not specific, I have just been reading source code lately, I read one blog where the guy was raving about how beautiful the Doom 3 source code was and one reason was all the proper use of const, so I was just researching away :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are careful, yes. But it is human to err. Also, you do not give the compiler the opportunity to optimize around these constants.

The error message that you get is because you try to alter a `const int`. Simply assigning the value to a (non-const) `int`, you alter it as you want to.

Const helps you, try to sprinkle more of it around and listen to the compiler. That will help you produce better code.

Comment: The compiler can generally not use the `const`-information as an aid when optimizing.

Comment: @Andreas: true in general, though in practice I have seen code that benefited from a const declaration of an automatic variable. That was on an old-ish GCC, though, and a newer one spotted that the non-const variable was never actually modified and applied the same modification. In that case, the optimisation to use an immediate value instead of an integer register, which of course only works because my variable was initialized with a value the compiler could see. Rather than try to guess what the compiler can or can't do, in theory and in practice, I just use const when I can.

Comment: @Steve That's why I wrote 'generally' ;) I would say it's a general misconception that `const` helps the compiler optimize. You should certainly use it everywhere you can, but for different reasons.

Comment: @Andreas: Sorry, I may not have made it clear that I do agree with you. My example was intended to show how feeble a situation it was that actually made an optimization difference: the compiler had the necessary information to optimize without const, as proved by the fact that a later version does so. It just wasn't smart enough. Optimisations where I'm smarter than the compiler are *very* late stage ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Even if you and everyone you work with never makes mistakes, the use of const in your method declarations helps to document your interface.

Comment: " if you and everyone you work with never makes mistakes"  Which, of course, is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

You lose some useful language features without const, especially regarding references.  Consider:

```
void f(const MyClass& m);
void f(const int& i);

// ...

f(MyClass()); // OK, can pass temporary as const reference
f(5); // OK as well, 5 is a temporary int
```

If you consider the 'const' optional and get rid of it:

```
void f(MyClass& m);
void f(int& i);

// ...

f(MyClass()); // Error, cannot pass temporary as non-const reference
f(5); // Error, same as above
```

Comment: Is it really useful to use scalar-typed temporary values, which do not exist after a function call?

Comment: Yes, absolutely!  Just for starters, how about: `SetPosition(vector2(0, 0));`

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid, but how the example you've provided does explain why is it useful to give a function a reference to an immutable int?

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind using 'const' is specifically that you ensure compiler errors when attempting to alter a variable's value when it has been predetermined (by using `const`) that you do NOT want to do so. It's essentially built in error-checking, and is useful for many reasons.

This is especially valuable in cases such as an external interface and public methods as a way of guaranteeing the caller that a passed value will not be modified.

`const` also locks in the intent to not modify, and prevents accidental assignment.

While making `const` use mandatory is unnecessary, it is very useful and good practice.

Here's a useful explanation you may want to check out: http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html

Answer (score 1):

You *can* forget about it but isn't it nice if the compiler forces it upon you?  That way, your "const" variables actually stay constant.

Answer (score 1):

Its always optional. If its all your code sure you can forget it ( I wouldn't recommend it, because it protects you), but when you interact with others, you're essentially providing a contract for them that you won't change their object or calling a function does not change the state of your object. This can be invaluable when you are not familiar with other's code, or you don't have the source.

Comment: Not always optional. For example, const references act differently from non-const references.

Comment: its optional in the fact that you don't have to use it if you don't want to code with that style. Regardless of its merits.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question first:

Yes, you can.  But only if you are careful, and everyone else who uses your code from now to eternity is also careful.

So, on balance you are better off thinking about why you *should* make something `const` and when you should not.

Another technique for exploring why const makes a difference is to try to make *everything* const at first until you have valid reasons to change something, then, and only then, remove the minimum number of consts until it works again.

Glad to see you are thinking about the issue - its more than most do.

Answer (score 0):

People usually face this problem when they start using the const keyword. Believe me, it really helps. Leave it to the compiler to take care of the cosntness of the variable, instead of you taking care to not alter its value anywhere.

Answer (score -4):

Changing things that shouldn't be changed is one of the most common sources of error.
It is therefore worthwhile specifying const because it prevents you from doing something wrong.  Why would you want to give that up?

```
const double PI = 3.14159265358979;

PI=4; // generates a compiler error (good)
```

There are some problems with the c++ notation, because a constant can only be initialized, not assigned the first time, and sometimes, you don't have the value at initialization time.

```
class A {
private:
  const int num;
public:
  A(int x, int y) : num(0) { // oops, I don't yet know what num should be
    while ( ... ) {

    }
    num = ...;
  }
};
```

The way out of this one is to define a private function that computes the value of num
but sometimes that means that instead of one clean block of code in the constructor, you are forced to split it into sections in awkward ways, just so you can initialize the variable.

```
class A {
private:
  const int num;
  int computeNum(int x, int y) { ... }
public:
  A(int x, int y) : num(f(x,y)) {
  }
};
```

Sometimes, you have a value that is generally supposed to be const, but you want to selectively override that when it semantically makes sense.  For example, social security numbers don't change, unless your identity is stolen.  So you have just one method, called createNewSSN() which changes the otherwise constant ssn

```
class Person {
private:
  const int ssn;
public:
  Person(int ssn_) : ssn(ssn_) {}

  void createNewSSN(int newssn) {
    log << "Changed SSN: " << ssn << " to " << newssn << "\n";
    *(int*)&ssn = newssn; // trust me, this is a special case....
  }
};
```

Comment: That \*(int\*)&n trick is new to me, but it looks like the const_cast's ilk. There's a reason const_cast has been called the worst feature in C++, and I've never seen it used except as a kludge to get around bad code that had been made politically inviolate.

Comment: That "trick" is undefined behavior. I seriously hope your SSN's aren't manipulated like that.

Comment: This is bad advice for multiple reasons.  First, if an SSN can change, then the member variable should not be const. Second, the `*(int*)` trick evokes undefined behavior.  Third, if you don't know the value of a const member at construction time, then when the compiler gives you an error it is telling you your design is wrong.  Its not telling you its time to become a compiler contortionist.

Comment: For all standard junkies the relevant passage is 7.1.5.1/4 "Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const
object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior."