# What is the point of declaring a variable constant in c++

Tags: c++, variables, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is const (c++) optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477461/is-const-c-optional)

In c++ or any programing language, what is the point of declaring a variable const or constant? I understand what const does, but isn't it safer to declare everything not constant, because doesn't the programmer know whether or not to change the variable? I just don't see the objective of const.

Answer (score 5):

If the programmer (or programming team) can successfully keep track of every detail of every variable and not accidentally assign a value to a constant, then by all means don't declare constants `const`.

The addition of `const` to the language is useful for preventing easily preventable errors, unlike languages of the dinosaur era where evil things would happen.

Here is an approximation of a bug I once had to track down in a huge FORTRAN 77 application.  FORTRAN 77 passes parameters by reference unless extraordinary measures are taken:

```
subroutine increment(i)
integer i

i = i + 1
end

subroutine process ()
call increment (1)
call someprocedure (1, 2, 3)
...
```

The result was that `someprocedure()` was called with (2, 2, 3)!

Comment: Ouch... modifying a literal value?  WTF?  I always wished I had learned to program in the days when you could really understand every detail about the machine you were programming for, but damn... this is nasty.

Answer (score 4):

> but isn't it safer to declare everything not constant, because doesn't the programmer know whether or not to change the variable?

That is exactly wrong. It is "safer" to ensure that what is supposed to be a constant value is not changed by mistake.  It conveys the intent of the value to all programmers who may stumble upon it in the future.  If a program assumes that a value should never change then why allow it to be?  That may potential cause very hard to track down bugs.

Don't assume your program is correct, make it so (as much as is possible) using the utilities that your language provides.  Most real-world projects are not completed by one guy sitting in his basement.  They involve multiple programmers and will be maintained for many years, often by a group of people who had nothing to do with the initial version.

Please don't make me or anyone else guess as to what your design decisions were, make them explicit whenever possible.  Hell, even you will forget what you were thinking when you come back to a program you haven't touched for some time.

Answer (score 1):

> because doesn't the programmer know whether or not to change the variable?

No. You will write a lot of code for other programmers. They may want to change that value.

Maybe, you make a mistake and you change the value unintentionally. If it was const, it wouldn't have let you. Const is also very useful for overloading operators.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right when you say that the  basic idea is to make sure constant variables prevents programming errors . But one additional use is that the interface you provide to your client also ensures that whatever you want to be const remains constant!It prevents people who use your code from violating the constraint.

This will come in handy especially in OOP. By making sure your object is const you can write a lot of code without worrying about the consequences. The objects could be used by a new programmer or a client who would have to keep the property. Const iterators are also very handy.

[This link should help you out](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html)

Answer (score 0):

const helps the compiler to optmize code. Temporaries are bound to const referances. So, the life time of temporaries can be increased a bit more using const.

Comment: `const` provides almost no actual support to the optimizer.  The bit about temporaries is true, however.

Answer (score 0):

In web programming, it can be so that the variable isn't changed (sometimes maliciously) via injection.

It also helps when you may accidentally change the variable but know ahead of time that that isn't desired.

Answer (score 0):

Constants are useful when writing huge programs, where you may get lost and forget what a variable (or constant) does or whether you are allowed to change it's value or not.

Moreover and more important, It's important in teamwork and in writing libraries for others. If you write code for others, they may change a variable you intend to keep with constant value, so declaring it as constant is much useful.

Also it's useful when you want to use the same number in places where only constants are allowed, for example, delcaring static arrays. In this case you cannot determine the size of the array with a variable, also it's very annoying to review all the code and change the number everytime you want to change the size of the array, so declaring that number as a constant is very useful and I really had an experience with it.

Hope that's convincing, that's what I remember for now, I will come back and edit should I remember something else.

Have a nice programming :)