# Why const after void/int declaration?

Tags: c++, function, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is const (c++) optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477461/is-const-c-optional)
>   [Constant Member Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691332/constant-member-functions)

I have seen different posts around about `int a() const`. My question is exactly why do we want to put the `const` keyword there? I know that it prevents us from making changes on members of the class the function is in, but so what?

We could just write a comment above the function and tell the coder not to make any changes to the class itself inside the function, but why do we really care about the `const` after the `void` declaration? In which scenarios may there be a better way to use for example `int a() const` instead of just `int a()` and does the compiled code change at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does make a difference. Consider `A` to be a class with a `print()` method. Then this:

```
const A a;
a.print();
```

only compiles is `print` is defined as `const`.

Of course, the main reason is to prevent any changes to the object inside the class. The

> We could just write a comment above the function and tell the coder not to make any changes to the class itself inside the function

is just wishful thinking. This doesn't really happen. So if someone doesn't read the comment (or does and ignores it), you'll get compiler errors.

There's also the benefit of optmization - the compiler can better parallelize tasks on `const` objects because it can assume they don't change between operations on them.

Answer (score 6):

There are three basic reasons to use `const` functions:

1) C++ only allows const references can be bound to temporaries. But if you don't have useful const functions, const references are useless.

2) Some libraries, such as the C++ standard library, provide specific semantic guarantees that only apply to const functions. For example, you are guaranteed on standard collections that you can access const functions of the collection from multiple threads concurrently.

3) It allows easy-to-make mistakes to be caught by the compiler. For example, if you intend to rely on the C++ standard container guarantee, if you use a const object, you only can call const functions. So a mistake, say someone modifying the code forgetting about the concurrency issues, will get caught at compile time. (Rather than when someone is relying on your program to do real work.)

Answer (score 2):

The benefit of declaring a member function const is, that the compiler will emit an error, if you modify the object. So, even if you modify the object accidentally, the compiler will catch your mistake.